# Как создавать сокеты?

Tags: сокеты, json, php, ajax, javascript

Как создавать сокеты?
Создавать 1 сокет для всех пользователей или для каждого свой?

Comment: эм, вы точно понимаете что такое сокет?..

Comment: объясните, может и не понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пользователи (процессы) находятся на разных машинах, то открыть один сокет на всех физически не получится, поскольку сокет - это точка соединения двух процессов, и если эти процессы физически разнесены, то и сокеты должны быть разнесены. Если же пользователи (процессы) находятся на одной машине, то они могут использовать общий сокет (по очереди).

Создаются сокеты согласно тому API, который используется. Например, для JavaScript открытие WebSocket'а:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8081/");

socket.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Opened");
};
socket.onclose = function () {
    console.log("Closed");
};
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log("Received:", event.data);
};
```

Comment: @Iron, 

    Если же пользователи (процессы) находятся на одной машине, то они могут использовать общий сокет (по очереди)

Как Вы представляете это на практике?

--

Вообще, говоря о сокетах, надо уточнять:  

1) о каком протоколе (хотя бы TCP или UDP) идет речь;  

2) если речь о TCP, то говорим о сервере или клиенте;  

3) если о сервере, то речь идет о сокете, передаваемом в accept() или получаемом из этого вызова.

--

Судя по тому, что ответ принят, автор вопроса в теме не разобрался. Советую начать с основ (сокеты, программирование на Си в \*nix).